# GData Youtube Upload Crashing for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, youtube, gdata

I'm trying to use the GData objective c project v1.12.0 to upload a video to youtube. I followed the following guide to get GData linked with my project:
http://mischneider.net/?p=377#comment-1277

It all seems to be linked properly, but I keep getting this error message:

> 2011-06-23 15:06:30.729[79217:207] * Assertion failure in -GDataServiceBase fetchObjectWithURL:objectClass:objectToPost:ETag:httpMethod:delegate:didFinishSelector:completionHandler:retryInvocationValue:ticket:, /Users/aalesia88/Desktop/VOKAL/Developement/SSB-Youtube/GData/BaseClasses/GDataServiceBase.m:603
>   2011-06-23 15:06:30.731[79217:207] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'GDataHTTPUploadFetcher needed'

Here is my methods used in calling the upload procedure:

```
- (GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *)youTubeService 
{
    GDataServiceGoogleYouTube* service = nil;

    if (!service) {
        service = [[GDataServiceGoogleYouTube alloc] init];

        [service setShouldCacheDatedData:YES];
        [service setServiceShouldFollowNextLinks:YES];
        [service setIsServiceRetryEnabled:YES];
    }

    SSBYoutubeCredentials *currentUser = [SSBYoutubeCredentials getCurrentUser];
    NSString *username = currentUser.username;
    NSString *password = currentUser.password;

    if ([username length] > 0 && [password length] > 0) {
        [service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:username
                                       password:password];
    } else {
        // fetch unauthenticated
        [service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:nil
                                       password:nil];
    }

    NSString *devKey = DEVELOPER_KEY;
    [service setYouTubeDeveloperKey:devKey];

    return service;
}

- (void)setUploadTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket 
{
    if (uploadTicket != nil) {
        [uploadTicket release];
    }

    uploadTicket = [ticket retain];
}

- (void)uploadVideoFile 
{    
    NSString *devKey = DEVELOPER_KEY;

    GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];
    [service setYouTubeDeveloperKey:devKey];

    SSBYoutubeCredentials *currentUser = [SSBYoutubeCredentials getCurrentUser];
    NSString *username = currentUser.username;

    NSURL *url = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeUploadURLForUserID:username];

    // load the file data
    NSString *path;
#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    path = self.videoPath;
#else
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"];;
#endif
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSString *filename = [path lastPathComponent];

    // gather all the metadata needed for the mediaGroup
    NSString *titleStr = self.trick;
    GDataMediaTitle *title = [GDataMediaTitle textConstructWithString:titleStr];

    NSString *categoryStr = @"SSB";
    GDataMediaCategory *category = [GDataMediaCategory mediaCategoryWithString:categoryStr];
    [category setScheme:kGDataSchemeYouTubeCategory];

    NSString *descStr = self.description;
    GDataMediaDescription *desc = [GDataMediaDescription textConstructWithString:descStr];

    NSString *keywordsStr = @"SuperShredBros";
    GDataMediaKeywords *keywords = [GDataMediaKeywords keywordsWithString:keywordsStr];

    BOOL isPrivate = NO;

    GDataYouTubeMediaGroup *mediaGroup = [GDataYouTubeMediaGroup mediaGroup];
    [mediaGroup setMediaTitle:title];
    [mediaGroup setMediaDescription:desc];
    [mediaGroup addMediaCategory:category];
    [mediaGroup setMediaKeywords:keywords];
    [mediaGroup setIsPrivate:isPrivate];

    NSString *mimeType = [GDataUtilities MIMETypeForFileAtPath:path
                                               defaultMIMEType:@"video/mp4"];

    // create the upload entry with the mediaGroup and the file
    GDataEntryYouTubeUpload *entry;
    entry = [GDataEntryYouTubeUpload uploadEntryWithMediaGroup:mediaGroup
                                                          data:data
                                                      MIMEType:mimeType
                                                          slug:filename];


    SEL progressSel = @selector(ticket:hasDeliveredByteCount:ofTotalByteCount:);
    [service setServiceUploadProgressSelector:progressSel];

    GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
    ticket = [service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:entry
                                      forFeedURL:url
                                        delegate:self
                                        didFinishSelector:@selector(uploadTicket:finishedWithEntry:error:)];

    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];
    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate;
    HUD.labelText = @"Uploading...";

    [self setUploadTicket:ticket];
}
```

If anyone has any insight into this problem that would be very helpful.

Thanks,
Anthony

Comment: Thanks for sharing this code for uploading the video. A Sidenote: You cannot freely choose the var categoryStr, it needs to be the name of an actual youtube category, or your upload will fail. Took me some time to figure out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is from GDataServiceBase.m.  It indicates that the class GTMHTTPUploadFetcher is not linked in to your application.

The class may be missing due to the class file not being linked in the debug or release build target, or due to the preprocessor define GDATA_INCLUDE_YOUTUBE_SERVICE not being set, as described under "Removing Unneeded Code" at http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary

Comment: where do I find GTMHTTPUploadFetcher files?

Comment: yes , where can i find GTMHTTPUploadFetcher?   it would be great help if any one has working demo project and can share it with me. my id is ravi.parmar@yahoo.in.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it seemed to be a linking issue. I followed the instructions on that link to compile directly into my code and removed the classes I didn't need such as googledocs. Once I did that, everything built fine and I was able to upload.

Thanks for the help.