# Assertion failure in GTLService with Google Drive upload

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use Google Drive in my iOS app. It authenticates and browses ok, but when I try to upload a file, I get the following error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[GTLService uploadFetcherWithRequest:fetcherService:params:](), /google-api-objectivec-client-read-only/Source/Objects/GTLService.m:565
```

Here's my relevant code:

```
GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:fileContent MIMEType:@"application/pdf"];

GTLDriveFile *file = [[GTLDriveFile alloc] init];
file.title = @"test.pdf";

GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:file uploadParameters:uploadParameters];

[self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                        GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                                        NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@"Done");
}];
```

Has anyone run into this problem? Obviously I'm missing something somewhere in the setup I guess but I have no idea what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I browsed through the source and the corresponding line is:

```
GTL_ASSERT(uploadClass != nil, @"GTMHTTPUploadFetcher needed");
```

A search for that on stackoverflow led to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6463772/254422):

> It indicates that the class GTMHTTPUploadFetcher is not linked in to your application.
>   The class may be missing due to the class file not being linked in the debug or release build target, or due to the preprocessor define GDATA_INCLUDE_YOUTUBE_SERVICE not being set, as described under "Removing Unneeded Code" at http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary

Answer (score 3):

Add -ObjC -all_load to the Other Linker Flags setting in the application project's Build Settings.

check  above step in https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios